# If statement only prints False

Tags: python, if-statement

I am trying to get day to print either true or false. It currently is only printing False no matter what the integer for "date" is given. I am new to Python so please bear with me if this is a rookie oversight.

```
def date():
    date = raw_input("Date (ex. Jun 19): ")
    date = date.split(' ')
    month = date[0]
    month = month[:3].title()
    day = date[1]
    day.isdigit()
    if day < 10:
            print "True"
    else:
            print "False"
```

Comment: `day.isdigit()` returns true or false depending on whether the string is entirely made up of numbers. It does not change the string in any way. So `day.isdigit()` by itself will not achieve anything.

Comment: grc, I had an inkling that may have been the case, when after using it, it did nothing. But, thank you for the clarification.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

in python 2 `raw_input` returns a string 
then you are comparing a string to an int thats why you're getting false

use the `int` keyword to convert the str to an int

```
if int(day) < 10:
```

like this

Answer (score 7):

`day` is a string, and in Python 2, [any string compares greater than any number](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#comparisons).

```
>>> "0" > 1
True
>>> "" > 100000000000000000000
True
```

This (consistent but arbitrary) behaviour has been changed in Python 3:

```
>>> "" > 100000000000000000000
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unorderable types: str() > int()
```

Comment: okay, I am learning Python for work purposes and here we are using 2.6.5. I have also tried the 10 parameter list this '10' and "10", same thing with "day"

Comment: Just do `day = int(day)` before comparing it to a number. Preferably wrapped in a `try/except` block in case `day` is not a string of only digits.

Answer (score 5):

`raw_input` returns a  string, so you should convert it to `int` first.

```
day = int(date[1])
```